# Animate.css promise sometimes doesn't clean the classes after animationEnd

Tags: javascript, animation, es6-promise

I have few titles in my page and I animate each of them with a different animation from Animate.css.
First I wrap every letter on the titles in a span element and then I use an event listener on the parent to see when is over it.
I use a event.target to determine which letter has been hover it and a parentNode to determine the class of it's parent and give the corresponding animation.

The problem is that sometimes some letter doesn't animate. I see that the letter still have the "animate__animated animate__(animation name)" from the previous hover.

I use the JS code from the Animate.css web sites that use promises.

Does anyone have idea why sometimes the classes are not cleaned? I see that I'm trying to animate a lot of elements but I'm not animating all of them together and at the end I use bubbling event to avit too my event lister.

```js
   /// wrap every letter in a span
  const words = document.querySelectorAll(".word");
  words.forEach(function (e) {
    e.innerHTML = e.textContent.replace(
      /\bCristian\b|([^\x00-\x40]|\w|\S)/g,
      (match, group) =>
        group == undefined
          ? `<span class="cristian">${match}</span>`
          : `<span class="letter">${match}</span>`
    );
  });
 // anim letters function
  const animationsSettings = [
    ["fede", "rubberBand"],
    ["myne", "bounce"],
    ["skills", "jello"],
    ["contact", "wobble"],
    ["tools", "swing"],
  ];
  const animationPrefix = "animate__";
  const defAnimationName = "jello";
  let animationName = defAnimationName;

  const regexClasses = () => {
    let regex = ``;
    for (settings of animationsSettings) {
      regex += `\\b${settings[0]}\\b|`;
    }
    return regex.slice(0, -1);
  };

  const regexConst = new RegExp(regexClasses(), "");

  function anim_letters(el, i) {
    // check if el is an event or not
    const node =
      el.originalEvent instanceof Event || el.target ? el.target : el;
    const parentClasses = node.parentNode.classList.value;
    const parentClassMatch = parentClasses.match(regexConst);

    if (
      node.tagName == "SPAN" &&
      node.className !== "word" &&
      node.className !== "cristian"
    ) {
      if (parentClassMatch) {
        for (settings of animationsSettings) {
          if (parentClassMatch[0] == settings[0]) {
            animationName = settings[1];
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        animationName = defAnimationName;
      }

      // We create a Promise and retu1rn it
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (i) {
          animationName = "jello";
          node.style.animationDelay = `${i * 0.1 + 0.2}s`;
        }
        node.classList.add(
          "animate__animated",
          `${animationPrefix}${animationName}`
        );

        // When the animation ends, we clean the classes and resolve the Promise
        function handleAnimationEnd(event) {
          event.stopPropagation();
          node.classList.remove(
            "animate__animated",
            `${animationPrefix}${animationName}`
          );
          node.style.animationDelay = "";
          resolve("animation ended");
        }

        node.addEventListener("animationend", handleAnimationEnd, {
          once: true,
        });
      });
    }
  }

  const lettersStart = document.querySelectorAll(".lettersstart>.letter");
  for (const [i, letter] of lettersStart.entries()) {
    anim_letters(letter, i);
  }

  for (e of words) {
    e.addEventListener("mouseover", anim_letters);
  }
```

```css
.letter{
display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h2 class="lettersstart word hi">Hi,</h2>
<h2 class="lettersstart im word">I'm
<span class="cristian">Cristian</span></h2>
<h3 class="myne word">Myne<wbr>social</h3>
<h3 class="fede word">Federico<wbr>Angeli</h3>
```

You can see the real page [here](https://cristiangiro.com)

Thanks

Comment: one thing I've noticed. The first letter always get stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `animationName` variable is global. When you animate a letter with class A, then hover over a letter with a different class B before the first animation is done, it will try to remove class B from the element at the end and be stuck with class A. You should be able to fix this by simply moving the

```
let animationName = defAnimationName;
```

declaration into the `anim_letters` function.

```js
/// wrap every letter in a span
const words = document.querySelectorAll(".word");
words.forEach(function (e) {
  e.innerHTML = e.textContent.replace(
    /\bCristian\b|([^\x00-\x40]|\w|\S)/g,
    (match, group) =>
      group == undefined
        ? `<span class="cristian">${match}</span>`
        : `<span class="letter">${match}</span>`
  );
  // FIXME: XSS issue if textContent contains <>
});

// anim letters function
// use a simple lookup map instead of complicated and fragile regex stuff
const animationsSettings = new Map([
  ["fede", "rubberBand"],
  ["myne", "bounce"],
  ["skills", "jello"],
  ["contact", "wobble"],
  ["tools", "swing"],
]);
const animationPrefix = "animate__";
const defAnimationName = "jello";

function anim_letters(el, i) {
  // check if el is an event or not
  const node = el.originalEvent instanceof Event || el.target ? el.target : el;

  if (node.tagName != "SPAN" || node.classList.contains("word") || node.classList.contains("cristian")) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  let animationName = defAnimationName
  for (const className of node.parentNode.classList) {
    if (animationsSettings.has(className)) {
      animationName = animationsSettings.get(className);
      break;
    }
  }
  if (i) {
    animationName = "jello";
    node.style.animationDelay = `${i * 0.1 + 0.2}s`;
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    node.classList.add(
      "animate__animated",
      `${animationPrefix}${animationName}`
    );
    // When the animation ends, we clean the classes and resolve the Promise
    function handleAnimationEnd(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      node.classList.remove(
        "animate__animated",
        `${animationPrefix}${animationName}`
      );
      node.style.animationDelay = "";
      resolve("animation ended");
    }
    node.addEventListener("animationend", handleAnimationEnd, {
      once: true,
    });
  });
}

const lettersStart = document.querySelectorAll(".lettersstart>.letter");
for (const [i, letter] of lettersStart.entries()) {
  anim_letters(letter, i);
}

for (e of words) {
  e.addEventListener("mouseover", anim_letters);
}
```

```css
.letter {
  display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h2 class="lettersstart word hi">Hi,</h2>
<h2 class="lettersstart im word">I'm
<span class="cristian">Cristian</span></h2>
<h3 class="myne word">Myne<wbr>social</h3>
<h3 class="fede word">Federico<wbr>Angeli</h3>
```

Comment: i can't believe that was that easy. You have no idea what I've done yesterday try to fix the problem XD. Thanks for all the other corrections too. I would like to understand more why that happened do you have any reading to suggest me?

Comment: sorry another thing what so you mean with "// FIXME: XSS issue if textContent contains <>"

Comment: You mean the `let animationName`? Read up on closures and asynchronous execution of code

Comment: Regarding the XSS issue: You would need to html-escape any `&<>` characters that appear in the text with `&amp;`, `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively, before assigning them to `innerHTML`.